# How run an encrypted webcam capture at login?

Tags: security, login, password, openssl, pam

I create a webcam video recording encrypted with a password situated at `/root/private/password` with

```
ffmpeg -i plughw:0,0 -f video4linux2 -s vga -i /dev/video0 -f ogg - | openssl enc -k /etc/password -aes-256-cbc > /var/log/webcam.ogg.aes-256-cbc
```

**Instead of using a password file, how would you suggest to directly encrypt the video thanks to the password entered at login?**

How would the `libpam-script` look like for this command?

Comment: when you say "thanks to the login password", do you mean you want openssl to encrypt the stream using your account's login password?

Comment: You can use `libpam_python`: [https://github.com/loristissino/pam-custom].  I cannot have permission to use the webcam interface however: authentication leads to `Cannot open video device /dev/video0: Permission denied`. How do I bypass this? [all code](https://github.com/higher-security/pam-encrypted-webcam)